# self coded SYS_CONTEXT

Tags: oracle, sybase

Quick one I hope.

I'm working on porting an application from oracle to another DB that doesn't support the concept of SYS_CONTEXT natively, so looking to roll my own with functions / SP, tables etc to mirror the functionality (set/get of name value pairs essentially).  I'm not an oracle guy, is there anything special about the way SYS_CONTEXT works I need to be aware of that will trip me up?

Comment: So you're only implementing the user-defined context namespaces? Or are you trying to replicate the `userenv` namespace too?

Comment: Mainly user defined, but any userenv calls I can fetch the equivalent from the system tables / functions as needed and mirror a similar response

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember about user-defined contexts is that they can be secured so that they may only be modified by a certain PL/SQL package.

Take this example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_context_pkg AS 
  PROCEDURE set_context_a ( p_value VARCHAR2 );
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_context_pkg AS 
  PROCEDURE set_context_a ( p_value VARCHAR2 ) IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('MY_CONTEXT','A',p_value);
  END;
END;

-- Tell Oracle that only my_context_pkg can modify context 
CREATE CONTEXT my_context USING my_context_pkg;

-- This will fail
EXEC DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('MY_CONTEXT','A','5');

-- This will succeed
EXEC my_context_pkg.set_context_a ('5');
```

Comment: Noted... if security is required we'll need to handle that as part of the solution